# Recuperar dados do banco no django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Meu projeto é uma simples tabela onde mostra países, número de casos de covid, mortes e recuperados. Pelo admin do Django já cadastrei dois países e agora quero recuperar esses dados e mostrar na rota, porém não está mostrando.

Link do projeto completo: https://github.com/PUC-DISCIPLINAS/monitorcoviddjango-monitor-django-guilherme-pedro
Esse é meu arquivo html:
https://github.com/CunhaGuilhermeBR/html/blob/main/index.html

Meu model, estou chamando de dados:

```
# Create your models here.
class Dados(models.Model):
 casos_confirmados =  models.IntegerField()
 mortes = models.IntegerField()
 recuperados = models.IntegerField()
 pais = models.CharField(max_length=100)

 def __int__(self):
     return(self.id)


 class Meta:
     db_table = 'dados'
```

E essa é minha view

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def list_data(request):
    dados = Dados.objects.all()
    print(dados.query)
    for d in dados:
      print(d)
    return render(request, 'index.html',{dados: dados})
```

O que ele imprime é: Dados object (1)
Dados object (2)
Lembrando que possuo dois países cadastrados. Queria descobrir o que estou fazendo de errado.

Answer (score 2):

Para recuperar valores do banco de dados para um html ou diretamente no console
em views

```
from .models import Dados
#Do model dados
dados = Dados.objects.all()# retorna todos os valores, mesmo são do tipo queryset
for i in list(dados): # para a forma de list e não queryset
   print(i) # valores
```

A função **str**(self), dentro do escopo da classe model retorna valores legíveis, pode ser especificado quais serão apresentados

```
def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.pais} {self.casos_confirmados} {self.mortes} {self.recuperados}'
```

A apresentação em um html precisa de um contexto, um dicionário;

```
def list_data(request):
     conteuto = {"casos": Dados.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'index.html',conteuto)
```

html:

```
 {% for caso in casos %}
  informações: {{caso}}
{% endfor %}
```

Esse código resolve a pergunta

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, funcionou direitinho. Agora na teoria o que eu estava fazendo errado era como eu passava os dados pro html e como eu iterava dentro do html? Obrigado de novo

Comment: Por nada, qualquer coisa estamos aqui para tentar ajudar. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
dados = Dados.objects.all().values_list
for d in dados:
   print(d)
```

Outra opção é usar o `values()`:

```
dados = Dados.objects.all().values()
```

Veja a possibilidade de usar [`__str__()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#str)
Exemplo da documentação:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Comment: A impressão no terminal agora está certa, mas os dados ainda não aparecem no html. Como prosseguir? A impressão foi essa :
(1, 5, 4, 1, 'Guatemala')
(2, 500, 400, 100, 'Japão')

Comment: Agora ele imprime certo, porém continua não exibindo esses dados no front.

{'id': 1, 'casos_confirmados': 5, 'mortes': 4, 'recuperados': 1, 'pais': 'Guatemala'}
{'id': 2, 'casos_confirmados': 500, 'mortes': 400, 'recuperados': 100, 'pais': 'Japão'}